# Binding Issue with XAML (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

My goal is to change the background color of a row in a data grid based on the whether or not a string contains the word "Outside". When I get to the Convert method below, the value is null, and I'm not sure why, but I suspect I messed something up with the binding in the xaml code, or the order of operations in my constructor. Any help would be great.

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="RapidPlanStarter.GeometryStatisticsReviewWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RapidPlanStarter"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="RapidPlanStarter: Geometry Stat Review" Height="900" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
    <local:TextToBackgroundBrushConverter x:Key="backgroundBrushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>        
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="659" Margin="45,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="710" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=theList}">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Item, Converter={StaticResource backgroundBrushConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Underlying class implementation:

```
namespace RapidPlanStarter
```

{
/// 
/// Interaction logic for GeometryStatisticsReviewWindow.xaml, a window designed to display the geometric statistics and outliers of the DVHEstimate
/// 
public partial class GeometryStatisticsReviewWindow : Window
{

```
    public List<GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_TextOnly> theList;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a window displaying the geometric statistics of the DVHEstimate model applied       
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plan"></param>
    public GeometryStatisticsReviewWindow(PlanSetup plan)
    {

        theList = GeometryStatisticsReviewHelper.GetDvhEstimateGeometryStatisticsAsList(plan);


        InitializeComponent();

        if( !GeometryStatisticsReviewHelper.HasAtLeastOneBeamWithCalculationLogContainingDvhEstimate(plan))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("This plan does not have any DVH Estimates, so there are not structure geometry results to review. Closing window"); Close();

        }  //end if no DVHEst results

        this.label_Model.Content = label_Model.Content + $" {GeometryStatisticsReviewHelper.GetDvhEstimationModel(plan)}";


        //made it here - must have some results to show
        CollectionViewSource itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("ItemCollectionViewSource"));
        //itemCollectionViewSource.Source = GeometryStatisticsReviewHelper.GetDvhEstimateGeometryStatisticsAsDataTable(plan).DefaultView;

        itemCollectionViewSource.Source = theList;



    }  //end const

    

}  //end GSRWindow
```

}  //end ns

And here is the object definition and Converter class. When this gets called by the Setter, the value is always null.

```
public class GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_TextOnly
{

    public GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_TextOnly(string id, List<string> reasonsForOutlier)
    {

        StructureId = id;
        ListOfParametersOutsideThresholdValue = "";

        

        if (reasonsForOutlier.Count() > 0)
        {
            

            textInsideOrOutsideThreshold = "Outside Threshold Values";


            foreach (string s in reasonsForOutlier)
            {

                int index = reasonsForOutlier.IndexOf(s);

                if (index != 0) { ListOfParametersOutsideThresholdValue += ", "; }

                ListOfParametersOutsideThresholdValue += $"[{index + 1}] {s}";


            }  //end foreach over reasons



        }
        else
        {

           

            textInsideOrOutsideThreshold = "Inside Threshold Values";


        }  //end if else outside


    }

    public string StructureId { get; set; }

    public string textInsideOrOutsideThreshold { get; set; }

    public string ListOfParametersOutsideThresholdValue { get; set; }


}  //GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_TextOnly

public class GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_WithBitmap : GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_TextOnly
{


    public BitmapImage resultImage { get; set; }



    public GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_WithBitmap(string id, List<string> reasonsForOutlier) : base(id, reasonsForOutlier)
    {

       

        string currentLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); 

        if (reasonsForOutlier.Count() > 0)
        {
            string imageLocation = currentLocation + @"\\Outlier.png";

            resultImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageLocation));
      

            foreach (string s in reasonsForOutlier)
            {

                int index = reasonsForOutlier.IndexOf(s);

                if (index!=0) { ListOfParametersOutsideThresholdValue += ", "; }
                
                ListOfParametersOutsideThresholdValue += $"[{index+1}] {s}";


            }  //end foreach over reasons



        } else
        {

            string imageLocation = currentLocation + @"\\Outlier.png";

            resultImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageLocation));

            
           


        }  //end if else outside



    }  //end const


}  //end classGeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults


public class TextToBackgroundBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_TextOnly recast = (GeometryStatisticsReviewSingleOarResults_TextOnly)value;

        
        //if(recast.textInsideOrOutsideThreshold.Contains("Outside")) { return Brushes.Yellow; }


        return Brushes.White;
    } //end Convert

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }  //ConvertBack end


}  //end BackgroundConverter clkass
```

}  //end ns

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't you just want the datacontext of the row? Value="{Binding .}"

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am asking for. Just trying to figure out how to correctly set the binding in this case

Comment: Read my comment above again. Because that's how.